# var not affected outside of function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, variables, jspdf

I am trying to convert an html into a pdf using jsPDF. However, the variable and things that happen inside a function seem to be invisible to everything outside of the function. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("#runpdf").click(function(event) 
    {
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        var imageData;
        html2canvas($("#page1"),
        {
            logging:true,
            profile:true,
            allowTaint:true,
            letterRendering: true,
            onrendered:function(canvas)
            {
                imageData= canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");      
                doc.addImage(imageData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 200, 200);

            }
        });
        doc.save('test.pdf');
    });
});
```

Upon running this, a blank page is rendered, notably that everything within the function `html2canvas` did not actually affect `var doc`. However, upon putting the `doc.save('test.pdf');` bit inside the function (after `doc.addImage()`), it executes fine with the page being rendered. However, I cannot do this because I am going to use a for-each loop to execute the `html2canvas` function multiple times on multiple pages and then at the end, save the document. But this won't work because it seems that the `doc.save()` needs to be in the same function as the rest. How can I avoid this problem?
Thanks
Edit: Problem fixed using a counter and simple if statement.

```
var doc = new jsPDF("p", "pt", "letter");
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    $("#runpdf").click(function (event) 
{
    $(document.body).width(1903);
    var count=0;
    $("section").each(function()
    {
        $(this).children('footer').children('article').append($(document.createElement('span')).text((count+1)+".").css("float","right").css("font-weight", "900").css("font-size","150%"));
        count++;
    });    
    var pages = $(".page5");
    var remaining = pages.length;
    pages.each(function () 
    {        
        html2canvas($(this), 
        {
            logging: true,
            profile: true,
            allowTaint: true,
            letterRendering: true,
            onrendered: function (canvas) 
            {
                var imageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
                doc.addImage(imageData, 'JPEG', -425, 0, 1450, 800);
                remaining--;
                if (remaining === 0) 
                {
                    doc.save('test.pdf');
                }
                doc.addPage();
            }
        });

    });

});
});
```

Thanks for the help, everybody

Comment: You need to learn about Javascript scopes. By specifying the `var` you are creating that variable in the new scope. Remove the `var` from doc and create `var doc` outside of the function to be accessed on the global scope.

Comment: It's because the `onrendered` function is **asynchronous** !

Comment: @David - I think you have the wrong end of what is happening here.

Comment: Or learn about variable scope in general and run the object method within the function scope rather than cluttering the global scope.

Comment: @adeneo  But say if I wanted to add a loop that executes html2canvas() for every "section" element on the page, and therefore need to use the doc.save() outside of the onrendered function, how can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put your save after you've added the image:

```
    html2canvas($("#page1"),
    {
        logging:true,
        profile:true,
        allowTaint:true,
        letterRendering: true,
        onrendered:function(canvas)
        {
            imageData= canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");      
            doc.addImage(imageData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 200, 200);
            doc.save('test.pdf');

        }
    });
```

The onrendered function is a callback and will be executed once the image is rendered.  In your code the save is being called prior to the image being added.

Comment: @PaddyThank you, this makes sense. But say if I wanted to add a loop that executes `html2canvas()` for every "section" element on the page, and therefore need to use the `doc.save()` outside of the onrendered function, how can I go about doing that?

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense. But say if I wanted to add a loop that executes html2canvas() for every "section" element on the page, and therefore need to use the doc.save() outside of the onrendered function, how can I go about doing that?

Comment: @yodofizzy - if you add a sample of what you are trying to achieve to your question, we may be able to help.  I don't have any specific knowledge of jspdf.

Comment: The problem was not with the jspdf, it turns out, I just had to get around that `onrendered` was asynchronous, so I ended up solving the problem with a counter.

Answer (score 2):

then you can save at `onrendered`

```
onrendered:function(canvas)
            {
                imageData= canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");      
                doc.addImage(imageData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 200, 200);
                doc.save('test.pdf');
            }
```

Comment: No but I don't want to do this. I need to save outside so that I can loop it

Comment: `onrendered` function is asynchronous, so outside of it will not waiting for it