# How to add a callback to occur after a JQuery each selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, callback, jspdf

I am trying to convert an html into a pdf using jsPDF. My code is:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("#runpdf").click(function(event) 
    {
    $(".page").each(function(){


        html2canvas($(this),
        {
            logging:true,
            profile:true,
            allowTaint:true,
            letterRendering: true,
            onrendered:function(canvas)
            {
                var imageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");     
                doc.addImage(imageData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 200, 200);

            }
        });

    });
    doc.save('test.pdf');
    });
});
```

This is meant to render a pdf with an image on it, however it gives a blank page. Apparently this is because `onrendered` is asynchronous and therefore `doc.save` executes before it is finished, giving a blank page before the `onrendered` function can add an image to it. How then, can I write a callback on the each function or something similar to ensure that `doc.save` does not execute until it is finished iterating through every instance of `$(".page")`?
Thanks!

Comment: Related question from same poster: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24369519/var-not-affected-outside-of-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to keep track of when the last one is done and then call `doc.save()`.  Here's an implementation where I just put the `doc.save()` in the `onrendered` function.  If you'd rather, you can call a callback there and have the `doc.save()` in the callback.  Here's the general idea:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#runpdf").click(function (event) {
        var pages = $(".page");
        // initialize count of how many left to go
        var remaining = pages.length;
        pages.each(function () {
            html2canvas($(this), {
                logging: true,
                profile: true,
                allowTaint: true,
                letterRendering: true,
                onrendered: function (canvas) {
                    var imageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
                    doc.addImage(imageData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 200, 200);
                    --remaining;
                    // if all are done, the call save
                    if (remaining === 0) {
                        doc.save('test.pdf');
                    }
                }
            });

        });

    });
});
```

Also, I suspect this doesn't work if you click the `#runpdf` button a second time.  You may want to move the initialization of `doc` into the click handler.

Comment: @yodofizzy please accept the other answer, using jQuery `$.Deferred` really is the best solution and you'll learn an incredibly powerful technique in the process.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! This is exactly what I needed. Thanks. Haha I'm pretty new to all of this javascript and jquery and callbacks(am familiar with java though and basic programming) and stuff and so I was trying to use that assuming the answer was hidden somewhere in there, searching through old forum threads, tutorials and documentations, and now I feel really dumb upon realizing what I needed could've easily be done with a simple counter and an if statement. Thanks again.

Comment: @Alnitak - when the underlying operation isn't already creating promises for you already, it's certainly not clear to me that the promise-based solution is cleaner.  It's a different technique that involves more code.   No doubt deferreds are a powerful concept, but not always the simplest way to do things.  I use them all the time, particularly when the underlying operations are already returning promises (such as jQuery Ajax).  But, in this case, I can't honestly say that creating a bunch of deferreds is simpler.

Comment: indeed they're not necessarily _simpler_, but they're certainly cleaner.  Compare in the other answer how it decouples the `doc.save` call from the inside of the `.each` loop, retaining the OP's original code structure even though the stuff that happens in the middle is all async.

Comment: @Alnitak - I'm just tired of people promoting promise based solutions as ALWAYS the best answer (because they're the latest neat toy).  They are sometimes vastly simpler and sometimes not at all.  They should be used when they provide a meaningful advantage and not used when they just make things more complicated.  There is no way you can say that Jordan's answer is simpler to understand for a newbie JS user than mine is.  And, I don't see any meaningful implementation advantage of the promise implementation either.

Comment: Granted I'm biased, but the promises solution obviously doesn't involve more code (I didn't count but, not including comments, it seems to be pretty much the same number of lines), and counting the number of items in an array to check if all of the operations are done seems very fragile and not at all clean to me. Promises may be "new" in JavaScript compared to, say, `for` loops, but Promises/A was introduced in 2008 or 2009 and jQuery.Deferred showed up in January 2011. In this industry that's hardly new. Regardless, if ever there was an obvious use case for $.Deferred, this is it.

Comment: @Jordan - Pretty funny that you think counting is fragile because that's all `$.when()` is doing.  It uses a variable named `remaining` that it initializes based on the length of the array passed to `$.when()` and decrements upon each resolve and checks to see when it hits zero.  It's the exact same technique just put in a different package.  It's not fragile at all.

Comment: If it's "the exact same technique," why wouldn't you use a mature implementation that, since 2011, has been the backbone of literally the most-used JavaScript package on Earth? Does it really make sense to roll your own implementation of a feature jQuery provides when you're already using jQuery in your project?

Comment: @Jordan - I've spoken my piece about simplicity.  Try stepping through `$.when()` when you're trying to figure out why things aren't working as you want.  It's very complex with multiple levels of closures.  Then, try stepping through my solution.  It's very obvious which one contains less complexity.  Pulling in an obtusely written library (which is an indictment of the jQuery promise code, not of promises in general) is not always the best solution.  Promises have their place and usefulness - it just isn't everywhere that they could be used.

Answer (score 3):

This is the perfect use case for [jQuery.Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/), which is jQuery's implementation of Promises.

In short, you create a Deferred object for each `html2canvas` operation, and then in the `onrendered` callback call `deferred.resolve()`. Then after the loop, call `$.when` with all of the Deferred objects as arguments. When all of the Deferreds are resolved, the `$.when` will be resolved and the function you give as a callback to `$.then`, which contains your call to `doc.save`, will be executed.

I haven't tested this code, but it should be more-or-less correct (I've marked the added code with `// ★★★`):

```
var doc = new jsPDF();

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#runpdf").click(function(event) {
    var deferreds = $(".page").map(function() {
      var dfd = $.Deferred(); // ★★★ create a new Deferred

      html2canvas($(this), {
        logging: true,
        profile: true,
        allowTaint: true,
        letterRendering: true,

        onrendered: function(canvas) {
          var imageData = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");     
          doc.addImage(imageData, 'JPEG', 0, 0, 200, 200);
          dfd.resolve(); // ★★★ resolved this Deferred
        }
      );

      return dfd.promise(); // ★★★ return a promise to be added to the array
                            // ★★★ that `$.map` returns
    });

    // ★★★ Use $.when to execute the `then` callback only when all of the
    // ★★★ Deferreds are resolved. Note: $.when.apply($, arr) is
    // ★★★ equivalent to $.when(arr[0], arr[1], ...)
    $.when.apply($, deferreds.get()).then(function() {
      doc.save('test.pdf');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: good answer, but consider using `.map` instead of `.each / push` to create the array of deferreds.

Comment: Oh, good call, @Alnitak. The array seemed a little smelly to me, too, but I couldn't think of a simple way to fix it.

Comment: The array isn't smelly, that's the correct approach - the code smell is using `.each` and `push` instead of `.map`, e.g. `var deferreds = $('.page').map(....).get()`.

Comment: p.s. don't forget to return the read-only `dfd.promise()` instead of the raw deferred object.

Comment: @Alnitak I've updated my code. Thanks for the suggestions. I didn't even know about `dfd.promise()`, so obviously you have more experience with jQuery.Deferred than I do. :)

Comment: I fixed an error but I don't see your edits - maybe they've overlapped?

Comment: I like this approach. Thanks.

Comment: @Jordan you've called the array `deferreds` when it's declared but just `dfds` in the `$.when` call.

Comment: @Alnitak Yeah, your edit clobbered mine. I've redone it.

Comment: OK, the last thing you're missing is a `.get()` call to turn the result of `.map` back into a real array.

Comment: Is this really simpler than a non-promises implementation?  I'm seeing the somewhat blind promotion of promises solutions when they are not necessarily a simpler way to solve the problem.  I'd ask the OP to judge the two solutions here for which one they fully understand and which one they think is simpler and gets their job done.  Promises have wonderful uses, but they aren't necessarily always the best tool.   They are natural when the underlying operation is creating promises like `$.ajax()`, but not always worth the trouble to make an operation into a promise that didn't already have one.

Comment: Well the promises approach does seem like a good idea, albeit much overly complicated for this purpose. It is a good idea though, and I have learned something from his post that I will use some other time, but for this purpose, the simple count and `if` is the way to go I think. Long story short: a good learn but unnecessary here. Thanks to everybody

Comment: @Jordan I tried your way of promise and it didn't work for me. Can you assist me. This is the link I posted `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40310036/exporting-multiple-images-to-single-pdf-using-html2canvas-jspdf-highcharts`